# DataGridView в PDF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, itextsharp

Есть кнопка "Отчет", которая создает pdf файл с названием Expo на диске d. как сделать, чтобы был выбор сохранить как, где можно было бы указать название файла и путь. Код ниже:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("d://Expo.pdf", FileMode.Create)); 
        doc.Open();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Expo: ");
        doc.Add(paragraph);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dgv2.Columns.Count);
        for (int j = 0; j < dgv2.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(dgv2.Columns[j].HeaderText));
        }
        table.HeaderRows = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dgv2.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                if (dgv2[k, i].Value != null)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dgv2[k, i].Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        doc.Add(table);
```

Comment: winforms? добавьте тогда соответствующий тег к вопросу.

Comment: Вам поможет [`SaveFileDialog`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @aepot Не очень пойму, как правильно вписать его, так как PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("d://Expo.pdf", FileMode.Create)); эта строка очень ругается сильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавьте `SaveFileDialog` в дизайнере формы в форму. Настройте ему там параметры, фильтры и т.д.
2. Попробуйте вот так

```csharp
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Expo: ");
            doc.Add(paragraph);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dgv2.Columns.Count);
            for (int j = 0; j < dgv2.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(dgv2.Columns[j].HeaderText));
            }
            table.HeaderRows = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dgv2.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (dgv2[k, i].Value != null)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(new Phrase(dgv2[k, i].Value.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.Add(table);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все получилось!